# Troubleshooting PHP High CPU on Production Server

Tags: php, debugging, central-processing-unit

We're trying to find a bug that will cause multiple PHP processes to be run at the same time and thus eating up the CPU resources for around 5 minutes.  During these 5 minutes, our server will totally inaccessible.

We can't seem to replicate the problem and not to mention seeing the same problem on our staging server.  My question is will installing xdebug on our production server help us finding the root of the problem?  Will xdebug affect our production servers performance?

Regards
Joe Thong

Comment: @OMG Ponies, it is very likely that there is a code issue causing the high cpu issue.  @user504789 I'm confused as to if it is happening on both servers or simply there production server?

Comment: You could check out some testing tools: http://www.opensourcetesting.org/performance.php I think this might work for your testing: http://p-unit.sourceforge.net/ but have never used it myself

Comment: @evolve, we are still not able to replicate this on the staging servers.

Answer (score 1):

in apache, set `ExtendedStatus On` if u have `mod_status` compiled
- http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_status.html#extendedstatus

with this, u able to monitor what are the URL that causing the infinite loop or spawn multiple background processes

or even simpler, log the time taken for apache to serve a single page - http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_log_config.html `%D` or `%T`
and diagnose the log file

Comment: thanks, but I forgot to mention we're using IIS 6, any similar tools or options?

Comment: @sujoe : it should has mod_status compiled, try `apache -l` to list module compiled, or simply start tracking the page processing time in your apache log